# Laravel build dynamic relationship Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, laravel-8

I've hit a bit of a roadblock conceptually recently.

I have a table called "Clients" where clients have digital managers (digitalManagers, belongsToMany, Users table through intermediate table) and regular managers (managers, belongsToMany, Users table through intermediate table).

Excerpt of relations from Clients table:

```php
/**
 * Get the assigned users (managers) to this client
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function managers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class,
        ClientAssignment::class,
        'client_id',
        'user_id'
    );
}


/**
 * Get the assigned digital managers for this client
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function digitalManagers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class,
        'digital_managers',
        'client_id',
        'user_id'
    );
}
```

Thus I can easily query digital managers via `Client::findOrFail(1)->digitalManagers()->get()`

Recently I wanted to add functionality to merge regular managers with digital managers for a client when a setting called `digital_merge_with_global` is true. I want to do this "dynamically" (I have my reasons) rather than updating the digitalManagers->users intermediate table every time a regular manager is added/removed.

I can accomplish this logic via the following code:

```php
$client = $client->load('digitalManagers:id,first_name,last_name,email,avatar', 'managers:id,first_name,last_name,email,avatar');

$definedDigitalManagers = $allManagers = $client->digitalManagers;

if ($client->settings->get('digital_merge_with_global') == true) {
    $regularManagersToAdd = $client->managers;

    foreach ($regularManagersToAdd as $manager) {
        if (!$definedDigitalManagers->contains('id', $manager->id)) {
            $allManagers->add($manager);
        }
    }
}
```

**But was wondering if there was a way that I could define this as a relationship (encapsulating the same logic but as some type of relationship) in place of the above `public function digitalManagers()` or if I am simply asking too much of Laravel.** I've looked through the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) but tbh some concepts are a bit above my head.

Ideally I'd like to run `Client::findOrFail(1)->digitalManagers()->get()` and get the output of the previous code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how much you strict to run `Client::findOrFail(1)->digitalManagers()->get()` and get output however, [extending collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections) can solve your issue in my opinion. Hereby, the sentence will be transformed to `Client::findOrFail(1)->get()->withAllManagers()`. You will be able to implement the logic of your code snippet in the macro created by you.
The below snippet shows the definition of macro which should be defined in a service provider.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Collection::macro('withAllManagers', function () {
    foreach ($this as $client) {
        $client = $client->load('digitalManagers:id,first_name,last_name,email,avatar', 'managers:id,first_name,last_name,email,avatar');

        $definedDigitalManagers = $allManagers = $client->digitalManagers;

        if ($client->settings->get('digital_merge_with_global') == true) {
            $regularManagersToAdd = $client->managers;

            foreach ($regularManagersToAdd as $manager) {
                if (!$definedDigitalManagers->contains('id', $manager->id)) {
                    $allManagers->add($manager);
                }
            }
        }

        $client->allManagers = $allManagers;
    }

    return $this;
});
```

After adding macro, you will be use it as `Client::findOrFail(1)->get()->withAllManagers()`. I think it will solve your problem even if it might not be generated at the query level.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how much you strict to run"... And I am aware on how to modify relationships and add items to a collection (see code snippet above), but modifying a collection doesn't really address my question as collections are generated after a database query.

Comment: I've just updated my answer in order to clarify. You're right that it doesn't solve at the query level however I think this way will not be much more complex than the query level.